# How to count the sum in total probability law?

Tags: probability, summation, poisson-distribution

Suppose there are $n=2000$ laptops in the factory, some laptops are alright and some of them are defective. A laptop is defective with probability $p_1 = 0.001$. If a laptop is defective, a controller detects it with probability $p_2=0.9$ (and no chance they can mark an alright laptop as defective).

What is the probability that exactly $k$ defective laptops will be wrongly marked as alright by the controller?

I approached to the problem as follows: let $X$ be the number of defective laptops that were wrongly marked as alright by the controller, and let $Y$ be the number of defective laptops among the $n$ laptops we have. Then
$$P(X = k) = \sum\limits_{m=k}^n P(X=k|Y=m)P(Y=m)$$

We can safely assume $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(np_1)$, but can we assume $P(X=k|Y=m) \sim \text{Poisson}(m(1-p_2))$? Anyway, either we set $P(X=k|Y=m) = \dfrac{(m(1-p_2))^k}{k!}e^{-m(1-p_2)}$ or $P(X=k|Y=m) = \binom{m}{k}(1-p_2)^kp_2^{m-k}$, this sum isn't really computable.

Any ideas? I would really appreciate any clue to the solution. Or you can just write a comment "I tried it too and stuck with the sum", so I know it's not just me.

Comment: Toss ten coins.  Toss again those that show heads on the first toss.  What is the distribution for the count of coins which where *tossed twice* and show *heads again*?

Comment: @GrahamKemp I can see this is a reformulation of the initial problem. Do you think it’s just Bernoulli distribution with p1(1-p2) success rate?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a situation for using a Poisson Distribution.

You have $X$, the count for faulty detection of a defect *among* $n$ items, when the *rate of 'success'* for wrong detection is *independent and identical* for *each* of the items.   This 'success' rate is $p_1\cdot (1-p_2)$; the probability of having the defect *and* being wrongly declared defect free.

What family of distribution does this describe?

Comment: Did I understand right that you’re suggesting this is a classic Bernoulli scheme with N objects and p1(1-p2) success rate?

Comment: Yes, @Swistack , that is what it is.

Comment: well it would be hard to compute the answer as we would have to multiply large binomial coefficients by small probability. We can approximate this with Poisson distribution $\text{Poisson}(Np_1(1-p_2))$, can't we?

Comment: Also, from what you say it follows that $$P(X = k) = \sum\limits_{m=k}^n P(X=k|Y=m)P(Y=m) =  \sum\limits_{m=k}^n \binom{m}{k}(1-p_2)^kp_2^{m-k}\binom{n}{m}p_1^m(1-p_1)^{n-m} =\binom{n}{k}(p_1-p_1p_2)^k(1-p_1 + p_1p_2))^{n-k}$$, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,p_1(1-p_2))$

Comment: We can approximate it with Poisson distribution $\text{Poisson}(Np_1(1−p_2))$, since $N$ is large and $p_1(1−p_2)$ is small, can't we?

Comment: Well, yes, but why would you want to?  You seek $\mathsf P(X=k)$ when $X$ is binomial.  That is an *easier* calculation than using the Poisson approximation.

Comment: I think it would be hard to compute the answer without it as we would have to compute very large binomial coefficient multiplied by very small probability.